# Rabbitmq management UI issue with Firefox

Tags: firefox, rabbitmq

I'm trying to use rabbitmq management UI on Firefox, getting this error:

An error occurred during a connection to localhost:15671. SSL peer was unable to negotiate an acceptable set of security parameters. Error code: SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT

This works for me on **Chrome**.

Version Details:
Rabbitmq-3.6.5
Erlang-19.0
Firefox-48.0

Answer (score -1):

This is not an **rabbitMQ UI** issue.its browser level **certification** problem.You need to update that thing.

Firefox displays this error "**ssl_error_handshake_failure_alert**"  means that you do not have valid personal certificates in your browser. You can obtain new ones by going to http://ist.mit.edu/certificates and clicking on Get MIT Personal Certificate.

Please refer this link https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/728969 to get full knowledge about this